# c# object defining property nullable or not

Tags: c#

I have an object that contains the date of an event. In the database, I have a field called something like ObjectEventDateUTC that stores the UTC time at which the event occurred.

For now, I'm defining the c# objet class like this:

```
public class MyObject
{
   public DateTime EventDateUTC { get; set; }
   public DateTime EventDateUserTime { get; set; }
}
```

The property `EventDateUTC` gets set in a linq-to-sql query that runs against the database and the field `EventDateUserTime` gets set later, in an encapsulated method that receives the user's timezone as a parameter.

My question is this: what happens to the field `EventDateUserTime` between the time the object is populated by the query and the time the property is set by the method. Should I keep my object definition as is or should I change `EventDateUserTime` to a Nullable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fields in a new object are wiped, i.e. the memory is set to all zeros. Then field initializers (if any) run, then the constructor (the CLI does the first step; the compiler combines the last two operations to make `.ctor()`).

Thus; they start as "all zero", i.e. `DateTime.MinValue` (1 Jan 0001). If you are content to treat that as an implicit null (as was necessary in 1.0), then fine. If you want something more explicit, then `DateTime?` is fine too.

Comment: ok, thanks; I'll leave it as is then. One more question, what happens to people who work in history when a datetime might be in the 5th century BC if the minimum value is 1900?

Comment: @frenchie people needing to work with BC dates wouldn't use `DateTime` - but also they *generally* aren't interested in the time portion; so I would **expect** them to use an `int` offset in days from some arbitrary epoch, maybe the BC/CE split, with -ve as BV and +ve as CE.

Comment: ok, I was just curious how it was handled. Besides, I'm sure it's not that common anyway.

Comment: @frenchie particle physicist probably need bigger numbers, of course ;p

Comment: @frenchie: Why would that be a problem? DateTime will cover 1/1/0001 to 12/31/9999. That covers the 15th century (1400 - 1499). If you want to cover B.C.E dates or dates beyond 9999 then you'd have to roll your own date type.

Comment: @MattBurland: I was just being curious. My app deals with contemporary dates but now that you mention it, do you think I should roll out my own date type to avoid future scaling issues when year 9999 is reached? Just kidding of course:)

Comment: @frenchie: Absolutely. It's shocking the Microsoft decided to ignore the obvious Y10K bug in their DateTime!

Answer (score 2):

> what happens to the field EventDateUserTime between the time the object is populated by the query and the time the property is set by the method

It gets initialized to its default value (`DateTime.MinValue`). You don't need to set it to a nullable type.

Comment: ok, thanks; I'll leave it as is then. One more question, what happens to people who work in history when a datetime might be in the 15th century if the minimum value is 1900?

Comment: @frenchie - This is an issue with SQL. They find some _alternative_ means of representation in SQL and convert to `DateTime` in code.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I keep my object definition as is or should I change EventDateUserTime to a Nullable.

Ultimately, this depends on your design: if the state of the object with unset `EventDateUserTime` is legitimate, make the field nullable; if you *always* set it right after retrieving from LINQ, keep it non-nullable.

Perhaps a better approach would be to make `EventDateUserTime` a calculated property, and store the user time zone instead:

```
public class MyObject {
    public TimeZone UserTimeZone { get; set; }
    public DateTime EventDateUTC { get; set; }
    public DateTime EventDateUserTime {
        get {
            // Calculate time based on EventDateUTC and UserTimeZone
        }
    }
}
```